# Starting eXtreme Scale containers automatically

Tags: java, websphere, enterprise, grid-computing, ibm-wxs

I am stuck at trying to deploy war application which contains objectGrid.xml and objectGridDeployment.xml in its META-INF directory and should according to documentation (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wxsinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.extremescale.admin.doc%2Ftxsstartwas.html) automatically start new container grid. But it doesn't :( More than that, if I make a mistake in XML server would not see it.

I decided to go back and test at least tutorial (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/714470bb-75c8-4f99-8aca-766c0d55a21c/entry/websphere_extreme_scale_getting_started_with_websphere_application_server_sample5?lang=en) but it doesn't work either.

Please help!

My environment:

1. WebSphere Liberty Profile for Developers (installed from wlp-developers-runtime-8.5.5.0.jar)
2. WebSphere eXtreme Scale (installed from wxs-wlp_8.6.0.4.jar)
3. Configuration files in attachments and my war application (http://we.tl/VRn98fooP5)

Comment: Have you solved this? How are you testing it?

Comment: I haven't solved it. But I've found a workaround of using standalone javase application as server application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking at the instructions for Websphere Application Server.

For extreme scale 8.6.0.8 and before on Liberty Profile, the configuration files (objectgrid xml and deployment xml) should be placed in [server name]/grids folder.

Please give this tutorial a try

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSTVLU_8.6.0/com.ibm.websphere.extremescale.doc/txstutliberty.html?lang=en

I think lesson 2.3 is what you are looking for.  It also mentions a eclipse tool that help generating configuration files

Please note that extreme scale features need to be enabled in Liberty Profile server.  lesson 2.2 has the instructions, which use the same eclipse tool, to generate the necessary server configuration.

Hope it helps

Comment: More than one year ago I fortunately made this eXtreme Scale PoC. Since then our company hasn't decided to use it. So I'll keep your advice till the moment it is required again. And thank you, Abelard, for replying indeed.